# How to examine multiple conditions in multiple cells at the same time in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How to examine multiple conditions in multiple cells at the same time in excel

### State of art

In cell A1, I have room number which must be cleaned (e.g. 102, 420, ...)
In cell B1, I have month name
In cell C1, I have the floor number
In cell D1, I want to insert "Yes" or "No" to indicate if the room in that month must be cleaned or not.

### Conditions

I want to insert a formula in D1 according to the following conditions:

If A1 is "100" **or** "200" **or** "300" **and at the same time**
If B1 is "April" **or** "August" **or** "December"  **and at the same time**
If C1 is "1" **or** "3" **or** "5"

then insert "Yes", otherwise "No".

Comment: What have you tried already? This can be done with a very simple IF formula.

Comment: The problem is that, I am not capable to combine AND and OR together with if.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that:

```
=IF(AND(OR(A1=100,A1=200,A1=300),OR(B1="April",B1="August",B1="December"),OR(C1=1,C1=3,C1=5)),"Yes", "No")
```

For longer expressions you might consider using `MATCH` as a shortcut, for instance

`NOT(ISNA(MATCH(A1,{100,200,300},0)))` in place of

`AND(OR(A1=100,A1=200,A1=300)`

where `{100,200,300}` is the array to match against. If the vales of the array are saved in cells `K1`, `K2`, `K3` this becomes shorter by using the Excel range `K1:K3`:

`NOT(ISNA(MATCH(A1,K1:K3,0)))`

Comment: That's my answer. Thank you so much.

Comment: Just one thing, is it possible to use array, in order to reduce the repetition of cell addresses? For example: A1={100;200;300}.